# Need Some Help w/ Nested For Loops in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, nested

I know this is extremely simple, but I need help with printing a code that displays

```
1
2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 10
```

For some reason, my brain can't figure out how to do it, even though I am familiar with for loops, this is what I have so far.

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 4; ++i)
{
 for(int j = 1; j <= i; ++j)
 {
    System.out.print(j);
 }
 System.out.println(" ");
}
```

I don't know what to do from here, it's been bugging me all day. Thank you!

Comment: How about using three variables - one for the row, one for the column, and one for the number you're going to print?

Comment: I don't think I need more than two for loops. I need to change something but I am not sure what.

Comment: You are correct.  Two for loops seems quite sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int counter = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; ++i) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; ++j) {
        System.out.print(counter++);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Use a counter variable to reach `10`. Also move the `space` in the inner loop and add a `line break` in the outer loop.

Output:

```
1 
2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int i=0,j=0,n=4,k=1;
        for(i=1; i<n+1; i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<i; j++)
                System.out.print(" "+k++);
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
```